# Универсальная верстка под разные браузеры

Tags: html, книги, вёрстка

У меня такая проблема. После верстки *web* страницы я просматриваю результат на четырех самых популярных браузерах: проверяю на отсутствие ошибок. Но как только я захожу на страницу с чужого компьютера (Explorer более старой версии), страницу как будто кто-то изуродовал. Подскажите, как добиться универсальности для всех вариантов браузеров? Дайте пожалуйста дельный совет или посоветуйте литературу, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/18814/262779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам давно занимаюсь веб разработкой, также сталкивался с этой проблемой. В частности для IE есть специальные комментарии с условиями, при помощи которых Вы можете скажем подгрузить дополнительный CSS файл, для той, или иной версии браузера. Подробнее [на MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx)

Также как вариант, есть решения непосредственно для CSS - это более элегантный вариант. Подробнее [на Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/css-browser-hacks)

Comment: Спасибо!) Теперь буду учить английский..)

Answer (score 2):

Практически любую страницу можно сверстать, чтоб она сносно отображалась в IE6 и нормально в браузерах. У меня происходит вёрстка:

- Пол часа — нарезка макета
- Час - два вёрстка
- Два часа — оптимизация под IE6

Можно часами ругаться на ослика, писать гневные статьи... Но если заказчик требует, то надо сделать!

И в большинстве случаев можно обойтись без условных меток ( if (IE6) ... )

Comment: Как я понял оптимизация идет путем добавления или исправления стилей. Верно?
И с какими еще браузерами могут быть конфликты?

Comment: Ве, сообразил, другие браузера работают нормально. И вопрос о функциональности именно шестого IE, давно уже избитый, и можно сказать продуманный.
Лучший вариант, это забить на этот браузер, в скором времени эта веб заноза, уйдет сама.(так как она уже слишком старая, и не поддерживает современный язык разметки).
А в случае с заказчиком, выход - заломить цену, причем не маленькую, за такую дополнительную услугу (поддержка старых браузеров). В  большинстве случаев это работает.
 P.C. Студия Артемия Лебедева давно уже предоставляет такую услугу отдельно, за отдельную сумму.